# Backgrounding an app causes UIImagePickerController to return prematurely

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

We have application code based on the Apple PhotoLocations standard code example - slightly altered to allow the selection of video files:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/PhotoLocations/Introduction/Intro.html

When the user chooses a video file from gallery, the UIImagePickerController transparently converts the file to a more appropriate format/quality.

It appears that if the app is backgrounded during this conversion process, the UIImagePickerController prematurely fires `didFinishPickingImage` - even though the content is not ready, and never will be ready (the conversion process stops).

I have tested some other applications, including Outlook for iOS, and they are not exhibiting this behaviour - they are resilient to backgrounding during this process.
While I cannot be 100% sure they are using the UIImagePickerController - they are aesthetically identical - suggesting they are.

Has anyone come across this before? Shouldn't UIImagePickerController handle this scenario gracefully?

[image]

Comment: Did you set up a background task before you went into the background?

Comment: Thanks @matt - no we hadn't, I've put that in, and it appears to resolve the issue.
I'm assuming that should the video take, say, 10 minutes to convert, and the app is in the background the entire time - there is no way to guarantee that it will complete - as iOS could terminate it... still much better than how it works (or doesn't work) today.
Feel free to flesh out an 'answer' and I will accept it.